# Cordova Plugin Local Notifications - No Sound

Tags: cordova, audio, ionic-framework, localnotification

Im trying to have my Ionic App push a local notification when the users location changes as a reminder for them to complete a task. My environment is using the following CLI's

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.1.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.0
Ionic Version: 1.1.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.5.1-beta.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 4.1.1 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v0.10.40
Xcode version: Xcode 7.0.1 Build version 7A1001
```

Have tried the Android build on Windows 8 to make sure it wasnt an issue with the new OSX El Capitan update.

I have managed to push the popups on both iOS and Android successfully with the following code, but it doesn't seem to play sound on either of the devices `iPhone 4s running iOS 7` and `Galaxy S3 running 5.0.1`

```
window.plugin.notification.local.schedule({
     id: 1,
     title: "Title",
     text: "Your location has changed",
     sound: "file://sound/notification.mp3",
});
```

Both my `caf` and `mp3` sound files are in the `www/sound/notification.caf` directory. I have tried the following URL's in the sound variable but have still not been able to hear any sound.

```
iOS
sound: "www/sound/notification.caf"
sound: "file://sound/notification.caf"
sound: "res://platform_default" --to try get default sound to play

Android
sound: "file://sound/notification.mp3"
sound: "android.resource://[package_name]/raw/notification.mp3"
sound: "res://platform_default" --to try get default sound to play
```

Comment: Did you try not passing a sound property? It should default to platform_default